# Using readMaybe to read list of natural numbers

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I am using this function to read list of natural numbers from string in the following format: `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
readMaybeIntList :: String -> Maybe [Int]
readMaybeIntList line = case readMaybe line of
                          Just l -> return l
                          Nothing -> Nothing
```

Right now it only works for integers - what would be the correct way to check whether the numbers are natural? Should I modify the `Just l` clause to check whether all numbers are `>=0`? Is it a good idea to return `Nothing` from such nested `Just` clause?

Comment: not a very interesting answer, but i would say yes to both questions you raised

Comment: You can use something like `Just l | all (>=0) l -> ...`

Comment: Your case statement is equivalent to just `readMaybe line` in the same way that `if b then true else false` is equivalent to just `b`.

Comment: I am aware of that, just pasted this code as I think it should be modified that way (using `case`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're going to use `return` anyway to invoke the monad instance for `Maybe`, then I think I'd probably write:

```
import Text.Read
import Control.Monad

readMaybeNatList :: String -> Maybe [Int]
readMaybeNatList line = do
  ns <- readMaybe line
  guard $ all (>=0) ns
  return ns
```

which is a more idiomatic application of the `Maybe` monad.  Whether it's clearer than the explicit pattern-matching (and monad-free) alternative:

```
readMaybeNatList' :: String -> Maybe [Int]
readMaybeNatList' line =
  case readMaybe line of
    Just ns | all (>=0) ns -> Just ns
    _ -> Nothing
```

is probably a matter of opinion and intended audience.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `do`-notation and `guard` from `Control.Monad` to avoid the excessive pattern matching:

```
import Text.Read
import Control.Monad


readMaybeNatural :: String -> Maybe Int
readMaybeNatural str = do
  n <- readMaybe str
  guard $ n >= 0
  return n


readMaybeNaturals :: String -> Maybe [Int]
readMaybeNaturals =
  sequence . map readMaybeNatural . words
```

Comment: Also, `sequence . map f` = `traverse f`